# Laravel 8 Astrotomic/translatable dynamic locales

Tags: database, laravel-8, config, translation

My Laravel 8 application uses Astrotomic translatable package https://docs.astrotomic.info/laravel-translatable/ This takes available locales from config/translatable.php file. But I need to make it dynamic and pull available locales from database. Can anybody tell me how to do it? Thanks.